# iframe cross site issue after same site set to none

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, safari, samesite

Recent update of chrome 80 forced us to update tomcat 8.5 for samesite=none in context.xml file.

Our web application is working intermittently in an iFrame section of clients web application.

Even latest safari browser version 13.1 throws session expired issue because of jsessionid cookie is not set properly.

Is there any specific fix has been implemented ?